# javascript loop string comparison headache

Tags: javascript

```
        console.log(previousCompetitors);
        console.log(competitors);
        if(data.isVisible) {
            var moveIndexTo = [];
            for(var q=0; q<competitors.length;q++) {
                moveIndexTo.push(-1);
            }
            for(var i = 0; i<competitors.length; i++) {
                for(var j = 0; j<previousCompetitors.length; j++) {
                    console.log(competitors[i].name);
                    console.log(previousCompetitors[j].name);
                    if(competitors[i].name === previousCompetitors[j].name) {
                        moveIndexTo[j]= i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(moveIndexTo);
        }
```

I'm slowly going insane trying to figure out what is happening here. I have an array of competitor data that updates in order. They are both arrays and I want to track the changes from the previous ordering.

I console.log the data and can see that the data order has been changed yet every single time the moveIndexTo array ends up being [0,1,2,3,4,5] implying that previousCompetitors an Competitors have equal order. How can they be changed between when I console.log them at the top of the code block to when I perform the string comparison?

Competitors and previousCompetitors take roughly the form

[{name:'name1'},{name:'name2'},{name:'name3'},{name:'name4'},{name:'name5'},{name:'name6'}]

with a lot more going on in each object. So If that was previousCompetitors then competitors would be something like

[{name:'name6'},{name:'name2'},{name:'name3'},{name:'name4'},{name:'name5'},{name:'name1'}].

Note the switch of name1 and name6. So I would expect moveIndexTo to be [5,1,2,3,4,0].

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show a sample input and the corresponding desired output (i.e., example contents of `competitors` and `previousCompetitors`, and what `moveIndexTo` should be afterwards)?

Comment: The data is quite large and nested. But it is simply an array of objects each object has the name field as well as many others. My intention is to use moveIndexTo to record where the object at position j in previousCompetitors currently is in competitors by storing i at the jth index of moveToIndex.

Comment: I pasted your sample data and code into a fiddle, and the result was `[5,1,2,3,4,0]`, just like you expected: https://jsfiddle.net/1jxmsewr/

Comment: Sigh. I don't understand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any other code that modifies either array after the above loop? The console will (depending on the browser) have a live link to the actual objects, so if you didn't expand the arrays within the console until after other code updated them you'd see the latest version even though you log them in order. (You can get around this by logging strings: `console.log(JSON.stringify(competitors))`, etc.)

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thank you so much. I wasted more time than I care to think about thinking the data was different but in reality it was bound to the object in the console so competitors and previousCompetitors were the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this : `moveIndexTo[i] = j;`
fiddle at : https://jsfiddle.net/c9mbbpjj/

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Actually what you want is changes in context of currentCompetitors not previousCompetitors. So moving indices should be like above.

Comment: Except that the fiddle I posted 15 minutes before your answer shows that the OP's code produces the desired result as is: https://jsfiddle.net/1jxmsewr

Comment: No that doesn't change anything. Also nnnnnn has proven it works in isolation so it has to be something else that isn't a simple typo. But how it changes from before the for loops to inside the nested for loop is beyond me.

Comment: yeah. But the other way the result will lead to many undefined values in the array and that not true reflection of length of currentCompetitors. Think when both have different length. If you have made moveToIndex with currentCompetitors in context, you should push data with same array in context.

Comment: see, you have made moveToIndex array by a for loop with competitors